# Fill remaining height of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap `.row` with 3 `.col-md-4` inside. If one of them is longer than the others, free space appears. I want them to fill remaining height. Can you tell me, what should I do? I don't want to use absolute positioning and fixed size. I want it to be as responsive as possible. 
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH2pX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784), you can use negative margins:

```
.row {
  overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-"]{
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

[Live demo](http://www.bootply.com/HOcaJzSg47) before using negative margins.

[Live demo](http://www.bootply.com/iJonbw8k6c) after using negative margins.

Using this method will preserve the responsiveness.

**Edit**: This question is a possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784)